# Unity will not load on boot, or via command line. Enabling in CCSM does not stick

Tags: unity, ccsm

I really don't know what to do.  When I enable Unity in CCSM, it doesn't load.  When I close the app, the settings don't stick.  Updating and upgrading didn't help.  Running the unity command in the command line doesn't help.  ANy ideas?

Comment: Enabling Unity? It should not be togglable unless you use a different WM. What environment are you using?

Comment: I can toggle the plugin in CCSM

Comment: who is the dumb ass that market this as duplicate? i have the same problem and following the solution on the other thread is completely useless